# Does it make sense to mount a disk only when needed?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, mount

I have multiple disks in my computer and I'm using one of them for backups.  I do daily backups using rsync.  The disk is not used for anything else.  Does it make sense to only mount the filesystem before backup, then perform the backup (rsync), then unmount it again?  Does it affect the lifetime of the disk? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question can't be definitively answered - powering up and down disks puts stress on the disks, however it saves wear and tear, so it depends on the weaknesses/tradeoffs in the disk design and manufacture.

Depending on what is being backed up, mounting it only when required might provide a small amount of protection against malware, as the malware will probably not know to mount the disk if its not present - that said, if its a Linux system the threat is tiny anyway.

Comment: Thanks, but mount/umount does not power the disk on/off, or does it?

Comment: By itself it doesnt, however doing this prevents disk activity and depending on disk/os could result in disk spinning down later as a result. You can use hdparm to modify disk idle timeouts.

Comment: This is excellent, thanks for your answer!